# How to create an solid rectangular image with different colors and opacity based on percentage?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, python

Data:

[image]

I want to use the above data to create a solid rectangular box which would have a specified colour for each label and it should take up only that percentage space in that box. I am fairly new to using cv2 and am not very clear how to go about doing this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me!

```
import numpy as np
height = 100
width = 100
blank_image = np.zeros((height,width,3), np.uint8)

percentanges = [60, 30, 10]

# Label 1
xmin = 0
xmax = width
ymin = height - percentanges[0] 
ymax = height
cv2.rectangle(blank_image, (xmin, ymin), (xmax, ymax), (255, 165, 20), -1)

height = ymin

# Label 2
xmin = 0
xmax = width
ymin = height - percentanges[1]
ymax = height
cv2.rectangle(blank_image, (xmin, ymin), (xmax, ymax), (0, 165, 20), -1)

height = ymin
# Label 3
xmin = 0
xmax = width
ymin = height - percentanges[2]
ymax = height
cv2.rectangle(blank_image, (xmin, ymin), (xmax, ymax), (0, 0, 255), -1)

plt.imshow(blank_image)
```